# GWT prevent popup panel from opening

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I have a *MenuItem* that has a *ScheduledCommand* attached. When the user clicks on the menu, a new *PopupPanel* appears that has `autoHide` enabled. Now when the user clicks on the *MenuItem* while the popup is open, the panel gets closed, but immediately opens again as the *PopupPanel*'s close event fires as a click event on the menu item. Can somebody tell me how can I prevent the PopupPanel from opening in this case?

My code is something like this:

```
@UiField
protected MenuItem menuItem;

....

    menuItem.setScheduledCommand(new ScheduledCommand() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            PopupPanel window = new PopupPanel();
            window.init();
            window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<PopupPanel>() {
                @Override
                public void onClose(final CloseEvent<PopupPanel> event) {
                    // TODO Maybe something here?
                }
            });                
            window.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to do this by checking whether the last hovered element on the Menubar was the menuItem that opens the window. To do this, I had to subclass the default *MenuBar* class and exposing the `getSelectedItem()` method (it was protected by default, why?)

```
@UiField
MyMenuBar myMenuBar;

....

menuItem.setScheduledCommand(new ScheduledCommand() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                if (!wasHoveredWhenClosed) {
                    window.init();
                    window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<PopupPanel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClose(final CloseEvent<PopupPanel> event) {
                            wasHoveredWhenClosed = myMenuBar.getSelectedItem() != menuItem;
                        }
                    });
                    window.show();
                } else {
                    wasHoveredWhenClosed = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a single instance for the popup and use `PopupPanel#isShowing` method to hide or show the popup.

```
public class MyMenuClass{

    private PopupPanel window;
    ....
    ....
    menuItem.setScheduledCommand(new ScheduledCommand() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
             if(window==null){
                window = new PopupPanel(true);
                window.add(new Label("Hello close me!!!"));
            }
            if(window.isShowing()){
               window.hide();   
            }else{
                window.show();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how this would help me; the Popup autocloses whenever I click outside of it, and destroyes itself, which is fine. The problem is that if I click specifically on the Menuitem that initiates the popup, it gets displayed again. I want that Menuitem to behave like some kind of on/off button that displays/hides the popup.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear about the fact that the Panel does not overlap the Menuitem, e.g. both the Menu and the Popup are visible at the same time. So when you click on the MenuItem while the Popup is showing, the Popup autocloses (which is triggered by the MOUSEDOWN event), **then** the _menuItem.scheduledCommand_ gets executed (on the MOUSECLICK event after). But at this very moment, the Popup isn't visible, so it get displayed again. I want this to be avoided.

In fact, in your code, the `if(window.isShowing()){...}` block will never run.